# Divide to rows that return a count

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by, count

I am new to Postgres and I was wondering how to divide two columns and place that value into a new column or if that is possible with what I am currently working with. The two columns I am trying to divide into each other are already created by Count functions.

This is my current query:

```
select w.publisher_id, w.sub_id_2, COUNT(w.contact_id), COUNT(e.edocs_signed_date)
from leads_last_90_days w 
left join enrollments e on w.contact_id = e.contact_id
where w.sub_id is not null
group by w.publisher_id, w.sub_id_2
order by publisher_id desc
```

And this is what my results currently look like:

```
publisher_id   sub_id  count count
"1481"          "11"    148    4
"1481"          "7"      8     0
"1481"         "695"    209    6
"1481"         "266"     5     1
"1481"         "54"      95    2
```

How do I divide the last column into the third column to get a closing percentage in a fifth column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mathematical operators (such as `/`) in SQL. Note, however, that dividing two integers in PostgreSQL will result in [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), so you'll need to cast (at least one of) them to a real using the cast operator (`::`):

```
SELECT    w.publisher_id,
          w.sub_id_2,
          COUNT(w.contact_id),
          COUNT(e.edocs_signed_date)
          COUNT(w.contact_id)::real / COUNT(e.edocs_signed_date) AS percentage
FROM      leads_last_90_days w 
LEFT JOIN enrollments e ON w.contact_id = e.contact_id
WHERE     w.sub_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  w.publisher_id, w.sub_id_2
ORDER BY  publisher_id DESC
```